# Vectorized version of for-loop + numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, sparse-matrix

Background info:
I have a large number (N) of particles in 3D. For all particle *pairs* [i,j] that have certain properties, I compute a geometrical factor c[i,j]. Then I want to sum up the contribution of all pairs [i,j] for a fixed i and call this c[i] (and repeat this procedure for all particles i).

Typically the number of relevant pairs is much smaller than N^2, so having an (N,N)-dimensional array C with the relevant information at the positions [i,j] and a lot of zeros elsewhere is fairly quick with numpy, but also very inefficient in terms of memory usage.
So now I am just storing the C[i,j] for the relevant pairs and the particles forming the pairs in 1D arrays.

That is probably best illustrated in an example:
Say, I have two pairs consisting of the particles (3,5) and (3,10). Schematically, my variables then look like this (double-counting intended):

```
i = [3,3,5,10]  #list of particles i that form a pair
j = [5,10,3,3]  #corresponding particles j (not used in the later example) 
cij = [c35,c310,-c35,-c310] #(with actual numbers in reality)
```

Now it really boils down to finding an efficient vectorized way to rewrite the following for loop:

```
part_list=np.arange(N)
for a in part_list:
    cond = np.where(i == a)
    ci[a] = np.sum(cij[cond])
```

Other solutions I have thought of, but would like to avoid:

a) Parallelize the for-loop: Not feasible b/c this is embedded in an external loop which I want to parallelize at some point.

b) Write the for-loop in C and wrap it into Python: Seems like an overkill for this (hopefully) rather simple problem.

Comment: You could formulate it as sparse matrix multiplication (which should parallelize). Then store the cij in that sparse matrix. No need for lookups, which will prevent vectorization. Have you looked at [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html)?

Comment: Adding information to the previous comment. Sparse matrices don't store zeros, so you wont have memory problems.

Comment: Just from a first glance, this would work. For the moment I will stick with the numpy solution, but thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want with [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). If your particles where sequentially numbered from 0 up, you could simply do:

```
ci = np.bincount(i, weights= cij)
```

To see what this does:

```
>>> i = [3, 3, 5, 10]
>>> j = [5, 10, 3, 3]
>>> cij = [0.1, 0.2, -0.1, -0.2]
>>> np.bincount(i, weights= cij)
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.3,  0. , -0.1,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.2])
```

If you do not want all of those extra zeros, you could do something like:

```
>>> unq_i, inv_i = np.unique(i, return_inverse=True)
>>> unq_ci = np.bincount(inv_i, weights=cij)
>>> unq_i
array([ 3,  5, 10])
>>> unq_ci
array([ 0.3, -0.1, -0.2])
```

And you could later assign these unique values by doing something like:

```
ci[unq_i] = unq_ci
```

Comment: Great, the first part with the zeros is (almost) exactly what I need! I just need to make sure that ci is of dimension N by appending zeros after the last non-zero element (but that might not have been obvious from my question). Thanks a lot!